# Верификация пароля на спецсимволы

Tags: c#, list, test-automation

Главное условие чтоб в пароле была как минимум одна цифра, буква, и спец.символ. Не знаю как можно сделать проверку этого:

```
    Random random = new Random();

    List<string> letters = new List<string> {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
    "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v", "w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","e","f",
    "G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    List<int> numbers = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    List<string> specialSymbols = new List<string> {"!","@","#","№","$","%","^","&","*","-","_",
    "?","<",">"};

    List<string> newNumbers = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

    var summaryList = letters.Concat(newNumbers).Concat(specialSymbols);

    IEnumerable<string> list = summaryList.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(10);

    Console.Write("List<string> with letters: ");

    foreach (var element in letters)
    {
        Console.Write(element);
    }

    Console.Write("List<int> with numbers converted to string: ");

    foreach (var element in newNumbers)
    {
        Console.Write(element);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("List<string> with special symbols: ");

    foreach (var element in specialSymbols)
    {
        Console.Write(element);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    string password = "";

    Console.Write("Summary List<string> which contains 15 random characters for generating new password: ");

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
         password += element;
    }

    Console.Write(password);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Прошу дать ответ попроще, желательно, поскольку я в этом деле еще зеленый джун. 
Спасибо)

Comment: Не совсем понятно про автотест в теме. Задача в чем? Сгенерировать такой пароль или же написать код, который проверял бы пароль на корректность?

Comment: `((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})` через регулярку легче делать

Comment: Генерация пароля это одно, и ее можно сделать проще чем у вас, причем сразу валидных паролей. Проверка введенного пароля на соответствие требованиям - совсем другое, ее можно делать по разному, зависит от конечных требований.